# How to show a MessageBox message containing some label content?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I would like for the messagebox.show to say ("Sorry - You Lose, The number is","label1.Text"); but where it says label.text I want it to say the number that was generated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RandomNumber(0,99);
        button2.Enabled = true ;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Winner");
        if (textBox1.Text != label1.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry - You Lose, The number is{0}",label1.Text);            
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MessageBox.Show("Sorry - You Lose, The number is " + label1.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is {0}",label1.Text));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is{0}",label1.Text));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add String.Format to your call to MessageBox.Show.... Here is your code, moded to show what i mean.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RandomNumber(0,99);
        button2.Enabled = true ;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Winner");
        if (textBox1.Text != label1.Text)
            MessageBox.Show( String.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is{0}",label1.Text));            
    }
```